# Generating Sphinx autodoc compatible docstrings with Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm 5.0 autocompletes docstring when you start writing a function:

[image]

However this format does not to seem to follow any good best practice. How it is possible to change this, so that parameters would be in Sphinx autodoc format:

```
def communicate(self, bytes):
     """Communicate with devices

     :param bytes: Outgoing request as array of bytes
     """
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default docstring format by going to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools, and indicating your style of choice in the "Docstring format" dropdown box.
Sphinx uses **reStructuredText**

Comment: I got `Plain`, `Epytext`, `reStructuredText`, `Numpy` and `Google` with PYC-2016.1.4

Comment: @luckydonald Sphinx uses reStructuredText